# Cannot get the import of employer-employee relationship to work

Tags: import, relationships

I have successfully imported all my organisations and I'm now trying to import my contacts which are employees of these organisations. I've read the relevant sections in the CiviCRM cookbook and the CiviCRM online manual, but I can't get it to work.

I can import all contacts without a problem (around 3000 but have been playing and testing with just 10) but the relationship to the employer is never okay. Though i always checked "employee of" " organisation name match to contact".

*I get this error too when importing: *"Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->import() (line 854 of /home/kasomk/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php)."**

I've tried everything, been at it all (sun)day. So please help me! Who has a comprehensive step by step guido on how to import relations? Which fields need to be imported on which import, which duplicate checking should I do and how can i successfully import the relationships?

Kind regards
Stefan

Comment: confirm what version of civi you are on

Comment: I'm on the latest and greatest 4.7.24. Just upgraded because i thought it could be a bug. Hosting is with civihosting, they set up the CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan - in order to rule out it being a bug with your set up I would recommend you take an equivalent file and test on the Demo Site.

I just created a file with 3 cells

Peter | Davis | Acme

I had already created Org = Acme in http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

The import ran as expected.

Acme now has an 'employee' called peter Davis

Comment: Indeed, it works in the online platform, import links employer to employee as expected. Could it have anything to do with the localization i'm using?

Comment: You might have to clarify what you mean by 'localisations' eg do you mean Currency, Country etc. In which case, I would v much doubt it. If you mean 'things on your local set up' then yes much more likely